# Azure API Management and Call Orchestration

Tags: microservices, azure-api-management, orchestration

Imagine a simple microservices architecture with a Customer Microservice and an Order Microservice that both have separate databases.  The UI has a need to display all orders along with the customer name (stored only in the customer DB) in some sort of grid.

To facilitate, the architecture requires the use of an Orchestration Microservice that will make the calls to each of the APIs and return a combined result set.  The call to the orchestration service should be transparent to the client.  e.g.:

```
https://api.myservice.com/order/{id} -> routes to the Order Service
https://api.myservice.com/customer/{id} -> routes to the Customer Service
https://api.myservice.com/order -> routes to the Orchestration Service
```

Using Azure API Management, however, each API is required to have a unique suffix on the base URL.  This would require something like:

```
https://api.myservice.com/orchestration/order -> routes to the Orchestration Service
```

This would break the transparency rule.

Is there any trick in Azure API Management to make this work?  Should I just move to GraphQL - I was really trying to avoid the overhead of setting that up?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `/order` endpoint as an operation under the Order API itself and change the backend using the [`set-backend-service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policy to forward the request to your orchestrator instead.

Comment: interesting - the way it lays out, it seems like the API Management tool is strongly bound to the back end container app that it is associated with.  I will have to investigate and give some feedback once I check it out.

Comment: ultimately, I think we are going to go the route of GraphQL anyways and get some of the benefits there as opposed to an orchestration service.  But, this is good info

Comment: Well, each API is bound to a specific backend since for most scenarios, one backend service corresponds to one API endpoint. But with polices, you still have the option to add operations to an API that don't really depend on the common backend that the API is tied to.